# Trying to to compare two different classes of variables in R

Tags: r, plot

I am working in a dataset where some variables are characters and others are numeric. Out of tens of thousands of observations, some have received funding to do a project. Project is a character variable with different a few different options, depending on what they project they did; some observations just have "none" in that column.

I am trying to run some basic stats on the different possibilities within the Project variable. as well as run some plots to see where the different project recipients fall compared to other variables in the dataset, which are *mostly* numeric covariates.

For example, one piece of my code is `plot((Housing_Data$Project), (Housing_Data$Size))`; but I get a terrible visualization because I don't know how to look at the observations for one type of project at a time.

Can someone tell me how to do the equivalent of `(Housing_Data$Project, = "None")`? Or something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about a boxplot?

```
boxplot(Size ~ Project, data=Housing_Data)
```

Or for an individual project:

```
boxplot(Size ~ Project, data=Housing_Data, subset=Project == "None")
```

If `Project` is a "factor", then the above command will still show all levels, but with no data shown. To prevent this, convert it to a "character":

```
Housing_Data$Project <- as.character(Housing_Data$Project)
boxplot(Size ~ Project, data=Housing_Data, subset=Project == "None")
```

Comment: The individual project idea was what I was looking for. I was able to run the code you shared. However, the other programs also showed up in the boxplot, only as empty, but labeled, spaces. Do you know if it's possible to ignore the other programs and just have one showing (with no space or labels for the others)?

Comment: I guess that indicates `Project` is a "factor". You could convert the Project variable to a "character" class to prevent the others from appearing.

Comment: good catch! Any chance you know how to convert it to a character? I'd like to try your suggestion.

Comment: THANK YOU @Edward. you get a special badge of awesomeness